# wxwidgets classes to access file attributes

Tags: c++, file, function, attributes, wxwidgets

using `wxwidgets 2.8` with GCC `4.6.2` under `windows 8`

Problem: Does the wxwidgets framework have any class/functions to access file attributes, specifically the `HIDDEN` attribute?

Things I have already tried:

1. I know I can use the WIN32 api's `SetFileAttributes` but I do not want to adopt that as I would like to keep the code cross-platform.
2. I have already checked classes under wx such as: `wxFile`, `wxFileName` and functions under `filefn.h` but could not find anything.

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `wxFileName` doesn't have any support for this. "Hidden" attribute under Windows is really Windows-specific, so there is really nothing wrong with using Windows `::GetFileAttributes()` to test for it.

But having a method in `wxFileName` testing doing this under Windows and checking if the first character of the filename is a dot under Unix would be still useful, and not really difficult to implement, so if, by chance, you feel like adding it, please feel free to contribute it to wxWidgets.